# MySQL Header exclusion

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to return all columns from a group of tables I'm joining. We have some replacement data in columns to not publicly disclose certain information, each of those columns contains a very specific string after the columns original name. Is there a way to exclude those specific columns containing that string?

I saw this but I'm not sure if it's what I need.

```
WHERE uniqueID NOT IN 
    (SELECT uniqueID FROM mainstage)
```

Comment: You have two opposing contradictory requirements. "Return all columns" and "exclude specific columns". You can't do both without implementing field value masking for columns. If you aren't supposed to return specific columns, write your SQL without those columns.

Comment: Are you trying to limit the rows presented as per your query, or limit the columns presented, which would be done by only selecting the columns you want to show

Comment: I want limit the columns presented, removing the columns with the replacement data, its only used to keep real names private. Each of those columns is structured as [LastName!DVM.Demonstration]  The !DVM.Demonstration is the factor I want to remove the columns by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL for this. You can:

1. Run an initial query to list all the columns of the table(s) returned by the query.
2. Filter out the columns with the specific naming and leave the "good" ones.
3. Assemble a final query with the good columns, and run it.

Alternatively, you can run step #1 and step #2 at compile time, so at runtime the final query would already be assembled and you'll need to run step #3 only.